# How to upload an image and try to predict it using the DL model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm kinda new to the whole machine learning/deep learning field and I have a few doubts.

I was doing this tutorial on the tensorflow page, https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification, and everything went according to normal, but the tutorial ends at the validation loss/accuracy.

I was wondering on how I could upload a photo of my dog and put it in the model to test it, but I couldn't find an answer to that.

I tried using a few images of the training dataset to try to predict them, but the classes it predicts, along with the numbers predicted are weird, as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvCdv.jpg. My results are really similar to the tutorial's.

Can someone help me with that? Uploading the image and testing it and interpreting the classes along with the predicted numbers.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you running it in colab? Or offline on your computer?

Comment: Offline, using the jupyter notebook

Comment: so `.predict_classes` will automatically apply softmax, but `.predict` will output the raw results before softmax, so that's why it seems weird.

Comment: Okay, but usually those numbers are vectors with 2 numbers that represents both possibilities, they sum up to 1, for instance [0.2, 0.8]. In this case the numbers are really different from that and there is only one number for each prediction

Comment: first off this is binary classification, which means that for every image, there's only one prediction probability(one number for every image), you can make sure by looking at the last Dense layer(see the number one? that means one number for each image)

Comment: second, 

"usually those numbers are vectors with 2 numbers that represents both possibilities, they sum up to 1, for instance [0.2, 0.8]"

That is not true, they will not sum up to 1.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the explanations!

So, if I put the number 2 in the final Dense layer, will it output those vectors? Otherwise how could I reach that approach?

Comment: So, since it is a binary classification and there's only one number, they will probably not mean much to me without the softmax function in the ```.predict_classes```, right?

Comment: Yes they does not mean much before softmax. In some cases, you will want the confidence for that prediction(`.predict_classes` will round it off). You can either 

1. change `Dense(1)` to `Dense(1,activation='softmax')` and also `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)` to `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()`, then model.predict results will be after softmax   (that is what I would usually do)

2. apply softmax as postprocessing(using numpy)

Comment: Sure, you can put number 2 in the final Dense layer(need to change loss to CatergorialCrossEntropy). But still, it will not sum to 1. Of course, you can normalize the numbers so that they sum to 1, but I do not understand why do you need them to do so.

Comment: I don't. It just came up in our discussion and I wanted to know more about it. I only needed help interpreting the classes, but I think the algorithm is just bad, that's why it gives out false 0s and 1s. Do you know how to upload a new image and run it through the algorithm?